# Python Requests Custom Response Headers

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to access custom headers sent back to my client by the server, but I cant find them in any of the header objects in the response object listed in the [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)

Answer (score 1):

From [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-headers):

> We can view the server’s response headers using a Python dictionary:

```
>>> r.headers
{
   'content-encoding': 'gzip',
   'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
   'connection': 'close',
   'server': 'nginx/1.0.4',
   'x-runtime': '148ms',
   'etag': '"e1ca502697e5c9317743dc078f67693f"',
   'content-type': 'application/json'
}
```

Access specific header like this:

```
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'application/json'

>>> r.headers.get('content-type')
'application/json'
```